# I want to redirect all traffic to HTTPS and WWW at the same time

Tags: .htaccess

What I currently have is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code redirectly only to HTTPS  but not also from non Www to www

```
# Canonical https/www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried this code before

and I start getting urls like `https://www.www.example.com`  which is a disaster....

is there a proper code to do both at the same time HTTPS and WWW redirect?

Comment: I edited your question to be able to read it...